# Setting up a VPS DNS properly

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, vps

My VPS provider is digitalocean and I'm using namecheap for domains.

I did the setup following numerous tutorials but I'm not sure if I configured it properly, everything works properly as far as I know but I can't be 100% sure and I've read some nasty stories about configuring your dns wrong.

This is what I did:

From namecheap, I said my nameservers are:

ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
ns3.digitalocean.com

This is how I setup my digitalcoean DNS:

[image]

I don't need mail server, I don't use subdomains, I have only one domain per IP. Is that configuration enough in these conditions to tell I set it up properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that configuration looks fine for your intended use.

You have an A record set as the domain apex (the domain without any subdomain) and `www` pointed to the apex.

You don't actually *need* the `*` (wildcard) DNS record if you don't use subdomains - the wildcard will direct all possible hostnames under you domain (e.g. `foo.domain.com` and `bar.domain.com` and `foobar.domain.com`) to your apex.

I personally wouldn't use this functionality and instead define explicit subdomains/hostnames as and when you need them, as you may subject your VPS to unnecessary load if people try (and they might) to hit `mail.domain.com` via a brute-force scan.